# "What is meta" should be rephrased

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, meta

[`Stackapps.com/help/whats-meta`](https://stackapps.com/help/whats-meta) tells that there is "Meta Stack Apps". However there isn't.

[Stack Apps is its own meta](https://stackapps.com/tags/meta/info) and [meta](/questions/tagged/meta) is used to ask meta questions here.

Comment: See also [the duplicate bug report on Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185521/148310).